# Indexes on SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a limit on the number of indexes a database table can have in SQL Server?

Thanks

Comment: Yes there are limits that vary depending on the version.  Which version / edition are you asking about?

Comment: If you have to ask you probably have design issues :)

Comment: Far more than you should ever need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server 2008 R2 the Maximum Capacity Specification is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx):

There you will see that the 2008 R2 edition allows for 999 non-clustered indexes and one clustered index per table.

Comment: However if you should use all of those expect horrible performance on inserts!